# TypeError on val() called on li child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I use this code to order children from an ul. The select works fine but the value call in the error below. The li has a value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $("#sortable").children("li").length; i++) {
    sortedPlayerIds[i] = $("#sortable").children("li:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").val();
}
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: (c.value || "").replace is not a function
...d*)(?:n([+\-]?\d*))?/.exec(a[2]==="even"&&"2n"||a[2]==="odd"&&"2n+1"||!/\D/.test... jquery.min.js (linje 16)
```

I'm using:

`1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js`

`1.7.1/jquery.min.js`

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly you trying to achieve by this code? Can you provide html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's problem is in finding `$(this)` object in your loop, which one you get it with your counter, try this code:

```
$("#sortable li").each(function(){ 
     var x = $(this).text();
};
```

Comment: or change `var x` to `scorePlayerIds[index]`, and add **index** to as the function's parameter

Comment: The val() function returns values of form elements. A `<li>` has no value, to return! Maybe you mean `$(this).text()`?

Comment: You were right Armin, this solved it: $(this).attr("value"); I have just added a value attr on the li.

Comment: ok. It is fine. but how you are sorting the array in this way ? I removed by answer :)

Comment: It is because I'm using a ui-sortable and this code is sending the updated order to a webservice using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code given by you in error

`d*)(?:n([+\-]?\d*))?/.exec(a[2]==="even"&&"2n"||a[2]==="odd"&&"2n+1"||!/\D/.test` is present in jquery.min.js. Please Find(Ctrl+F) this line in [this jquery file](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js).

Right? Actually, it is not error related to jQuery. YOu are performing one jquery operation in wrong way. See where you have used function `.replace` in whole java script.